# ' invalid catalog entry ' error when create shift note using FM COCF_SN_CREATE_PP

Tags: abap

I am trying to create a shift note using the Function Module ***COCF_SN_CREATE_PP*** but when I entered the category value I get error

> ***invalid catalog entry***

How can I fix that error to create the note.

The image from the **SE37** for testing the FM:

[image: se37 " COCF_SN_CREATE_PP "]

I create the shift note with the same values in ***SHN1***, and it created normal, if I entered a wrong value in  category in FM, I get an error '***not exit value***'. I want to create a shift note using FM (***COCF_SN_CREATE_PP***). but I got an error with the category.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to omit this value while calling the FM, for me it works like this:

```
DATA: ret TYPE bapirettab.
DATA: num TYPE cocf_sn_notifnum.

CALL FUNCTION 'COCF_SN_CREATE_PP'
  EXPORTING
    i_workcenter          = '1111'
    i_incident_start_date = '20200609'
    i_incident_start_time = '101000'
  IMPORTING
    e_sn_number           = num
  TABLES
    et_return             = ret.
```

To verify your category input you can check `QPCD` table, all the categories reside in column `CODE` by `KATALOGART = 5`, however your customizing data can very.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
I have to enter a value for the catalog parameter, about your code.
did you test the shift note in the se37, and get the same error 'invalid catalog entry '

Comment: no, for me entering the catalog goes fine both in code and in se37. Validate your input against the table, maybe your catalog value is faulty

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem finally, it was in the IMG activity.

You have checked the following settings in Customizing for the Shift Note in the IMG activity Catalogs and Catalog Profiles for Notification Type :

For the desired notification type, choose a catalog profile, such as 000000001 general catalog profile.
In the Coding field, choose a catalog type, such as 9 defect types.
check the Prerequisites: https://help.sap.com/erp_hcm_ias2_2015_02/helpdata/en/f9/d2b65334e6b54ce10000000a174cb4/content.htm?no_cache=true